# Error starting ASP.NET State Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I get the following error when trying to start the ASP.NET State Service:

> Windows could not start the ASP.NET State Service service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Everything I found on google told me to go to the `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322` folder at the command prompt, and then type the following command: `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`

which I did and didn't solve the problem. The path to the executable in my case is 2.0: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_state.exe`.

So I tried the same comand on the v2 folder and I get the error:

> "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".

thanks in advace for any help

Comment: "incorrect format" is sometime 32/64 bit issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated [here](http://thelittlewolfsadventuresindotnet.blogspot.nl/2010/03/aspnet-state-service-system-cannot-find.html), it's trying to load the 32-bit version while you need the 64-bit. If this is applicable, open RegEdit (own risk and so on) and change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\ImagePath`
from  `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_state.exe` to `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_state.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You not need reinstall this service.
Just find in services "ASP.NET State Server" and start it. 
Also you can set up to start this service automaticaly in preferences.